# What precedent is there for my homebrew "skill" concept?

Tags: skills, fate, homebrew

I'm starting to use a skill-like mechanic for my NPCs which is kind of a cross between [modes](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/skill-modes) and the [aspects only](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/structural-changes#aspects-only) option. **I want to know what systems have used a feature like this**, so I can build on prior learning rather than re-inventing the wheel.

In [fate-core](/questions/tagged/fate-core), [skills describe your character's "competency" at a thing he can do](http://fate-srd.com/fate-core/skills-stunts#defining-skills). In [fate-accelerated](/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated), [approaches describe "how you accomplish tasks."](http://fate-srd.com/fate-accelerated/who-do-you-want-be#approaches) Instead of either of those options, I'm giving my NPCs an aspect/skill hybrid mechanic which describes what they *are* or *have* and assigns a roll modifier to using each feature. For example, a monster might have Teeth & Claws +3, Keen Senses +2, and Tremendous Bulk +4. "Teeth & Claws" can be used to attack, or climb, or rip down a door, but it's not good for defence--that'd be a Tremendous Bulk roll, as would ramming through a wall or blocking a doorway.

**Where can I find precedent for this skill/aspect hybrid mechanic?** And please, highlight the bits of the system's mechanics/advice/etc that you think will be most helpful in gleaning that system's learning for my own use of the conceit.

Answer (score 4):

[Prose Descriptive Qualities](http://www.atomicsockmonkey.com/freebies/di/pdq-core.pdf) has such a skill system, and works largely as you describe. The system is much looser than fate mechanically—no skills are defined by default. Note that the link might easily change, as it has already been removed from the freebies page site. Of note is the guidelines on specificity and overbroad skills.

[New Link](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/pdq/pdq-core.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Your first stop should be the classic **Over The Edge**, which uses Traits in a manner very close to what you describe. (A version of the rules is available as an open game system, the 
[WaRP System](http://www.atlas-games.com/warp/), [available for perusal here](http://www.atlas-games.com/pdf_storage/WaRPSystemPackage.zip).) Once you've seen that, check out [RISUS](http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/risus.htm) by S. John Ross, a game with a similar bent but more focused on humor.

Answer (score 3):

### Fate resources

There are some fate resources for this.

Its worth noting that the [fate system toolkit](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/other-solutions#professions) briefly touches on this concept. It talks about **Professions** as skills instead, This focus on what a character *is* is a similar approach.

Also, the Fate Core rulebook contains information on this approach in the information on the Fate Fractal / Bronze Rule. Most Notably in **Environmental Hazards** (p 208).

Finally, [Michael Moceri](https://plus.google.com/110434538393561345672/posts/4Bnjb2j3k5h) has an excellent example of how a haunted house can work as a fate character, using similar concepts to what you have included.

The best advice from these examples is to remember that when you add a skill, you also add in ways for the player to interact with that feature naturally as part of the design.  If a creature has **Tremendous bulk**, then it makes sense that a player could use an athletics check and ride it. Think about these sort of interactions in design and write down a few ideas. Always poke players in the direction of interesting interaction.